# How can I embed additional languages in TextMate 2's “HTML” bundle?

Tags: textmate, textmate-2

TextMate 2's "HTML" bundle ships with built-in support for highlighting HTML tags, the contents of CSS `<style>` tags, and the contents of JavaScript `<script>` tags. However, I'd like to configure it to also embed [Pug support](https://github.com/davidrios/pug-tmbundle) as well, and key off of the `<template lang="pug">` opening tag. How can I embed that Pug highlighter in the same way the existing CSS and JavaScript highlighters are embedded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this going. I installed the Pug tmBundle, then edited the built-in HTML bundle to include the following:

```
                {   begin = '(^[ \t]+)?(?=<(?i:template lang="pug")(?!-))';
                end = '(?!\G)([ \t]*$\n?)?';
                beginCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.whitespace.embedded.leading.html'; }; };
                endCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.whitespace.embedded.trailing.html'; }; };
                patterns = (
                    {   name = 'meta.embedded.block.html';
                        begin = '(?i)(<)(template)(?=\s|/?>)';
                        end = '(?i)((<)/)(template)\s*(>)';
                        beginCaptures = {
                            0 = { name = 'meta.tag.metadata.pug.start.html'; };
                            1 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html'; };
                            2 = { name = 'entity.name.tag.html'; };
                        };
                        endCaptures = {
                            0 = { name = 'meta.tag.metadata.pug.end.html'; };
                            1 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html'; };
                            2 = { name = 'source.pug'; };
                            3 = { name = 'entity.name.tag.html'; };
                            4 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.end.html'; };
                        };
                        patterns = (
                            {   name = 'meta.tag.metadata.pug.start.html';
                                begin = '\G';
                                end = '(>)';
                                captures = { 1 = { name = 'punctuation.definition.tag.end.html'; }; };
                                patterns = ( { include = '#attribute'; } );
                            },
                            {   name = 'source.pug';
                                begin = '(?!\G)';
                                end = '(?=</(?i:template))';
                                patterns = ( { include = 'source.pug'; } );
                            }
                        );
                    },
                );
            },
```

Add that above the `style` pattern, and the Pug highlighter will highlight `<template lang="pug">` blocks. In my case, this was inside `.vue` files.

Answer (score 0):

The github project
[pug-tmbundle](https://github.com/davidrios/pug-tmbundle)
might solve the problem.

The author, davidrios, gives this description:

> A TextMate Bundle for the Pug templating language. Implemented in
>   JSON-tmLanguage, a compiled tmLanguage version is included. All
>   language features that I know of (including some undocumented ones and
>   quircks of the Pug parser) and some indent increase/decrease patterns
>   are implemented.
>
> A highlighter using Python instead of JavaScript is also included for
>   use with PyPug, you can either manually select Pug (Python) from the
>   syntaxes list or give your file the extension .py.pug to select
>   automatically (only on Sublime Text). Also included is a test.py.pug
>   file that can be compiled with pypug to test it.

The latest update is from Sep 16, 2016, but the description also says:

> This was made specifically for Sublime Text 2, but was tested and **works with Textmate 2** and Sublime Text 3

Comment: davidrios' bundle adds Pug support to TextMate 2 (I even linked to it from the question), but critically, I need it to work within the context of a parent HTML bundle. I'm editing *.vue files that contain `<style>`, `<script>`, and `<template lang="pug">` syntaxes, but only the first two are currently supported by the HTML bundle. Thus, I'd like to _embed_ Pug support into an existing bundle. If I just install this bundle, `<template lang="pug">` blocks would be highlighted, but not the `<style>` and `<script>`.

Comment: I didn't see that you already linked to it. So you mean that tmbundle does a partial job and you are looking for something better?

Comment: I mean one that does all three. The built in HTML bundle does 2/3, and the aforelinked Pug bundle does 1/3, but I’m specifically interested in how to combine the two. The HTML bundle already embeds CSS and JavaScript, and I’d like to embed Pug as well :)

Comment: Is that you are looking for a better development tool? For example Visual Code with [Vetur](https://flaviocopes.com/vue-vscode/)? Which operating system?